# SQL question: how do I find the count of IDs that are always mapped to a 'true' field in another table

Tags: sql, where-clause, having-clause

I have a database that collects a list of document packages in one table and each individual page in another table

Each page has a PackageID connecting the two tables.

I'm trying to find the count of all packages where ALL pages connected to it have a boolean field (stored on the page table) of true. Even if 1/20 of the pages connected to the packageID is false, I don't want that packageID counted

Right now all I have is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pages.package_id)
FROM pages
WHERE boolean_field = true
```

But I'm not sure how to add that if one page w/ that package_id has the boolean_field != true than I don't want it counted. I also want to know the count of those packages that have any that are false.

I'm not sure if I need a subquery, if statement, having clause, or what.

Any direction even if it's what operators I should study on would be super helpful. Thanks :).

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: With Postgres you could use `having bool_and(boolean_field)`

Comment: What if a package has no pages?  In that case all pages are true . . . but they are all false too.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*)
from 
(
  select package_id
  from pages
  group by package_id
  having min(boolean_field) = 1
) tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to express this is:

```
select count(*)
from packages p
where not exists (select 1
                  from pages pp
                  where pp.package_id = p.package_id and
                        not pp.boolean_field
                 );
```

The advantage of this approach is that it avoids aggregation, which can be a big win performance wise.  It can also take advantage of an index on `pages(package_id, boolean_field)`.